# set focus to next input type when side arrow is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to skip hidden input type in td and set focus to next visible input type

here is the table for your reference

[image: table reference]

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" id="vitProb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="unitfocus0 ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label id="" class="centerlabeltext">0</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="" id="" class="" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="unitfocus1 ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="unitfocus2 ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="unitfocus4 ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="unitfocus5 ">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="" class="unitfocus6 ">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is the js code:**

```
$(document).delegate('table#vitProb tbody tr td input ' ,"keydown",function(e) {

  // get the code of the key that was pressed
  var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

  // varify that  side key was pressed
  if (code === 39) {

    // get the next tr's input field, and set focus to it
    var c=this.className;
    var a=c.split("");
    var m=a[9];

    if(isNaN(m))
    {   m=0;}
    else
    {m=parseInt(m)+1;}

    var n="unitfocus"+m;

    $(this).closest('td').next().find('input[text].'+n+'').focus();

    return false;
  }
  else if (code === 37) {

    // get the next tr's input field, and set focus to it
    var c=this.className;
    var a=c.split("");
    var m=a[9];
    m=parseInt(m)-1;
    if(m==0){m=0;}else{m;}
    ;
    var n="unitfocus"+m;

    $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input.'+n+'').focus();

    // prevent any default actions
    return false;
  }
});
```

As shown in an image next arrow works in first tr from year 1 to year 5, but in first tr arrow key doesn't work from share to first year

I Unit column there is hidden input type and label inside td

I think because of hidden field arrow key doesn't work from share to year 1

How to skip hidden fields and travel to next visible input type.

Comment: You could use the [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) like `:not(:hidden)`

Comment: Could you not just move the hidden field below the inputs?

Comment: :not(:hidden) not working

Comment: Have you already tried `:not([type=hidden])`?

Comment: I have tried dis still not working  $(this).closest('td').next().find(':input[type="text"]:enabled:visible:not("disabled")').focus();

Answer (score 0):

You already determine the classname of the next and previous elements.
There is no need to call the next() or prev() methods.
Here is a JSFiddle where first the parent tr is selected, and then the underlying td with the correct class:

http://jsfiddle.net/av6abz0f/

This is the line I've changed:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('input.'+n+'').focus();
```